# How can I align li tags symmetrically on mobile irrespective on length of the text?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Please have a look at these two images. This is how my website looks when I view it on a

Mobile
[image: How it looks on an iPhone]

Desktop
[image: How it looks on a desktop]

I have used simple ul and li tags for this list. How can I adjust the symmetry so that each li gets 50% width on a mobile and everything looks symmetrical on a phone.

I am using bootstrap, so if there is a bootstrap solution, that will be good.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use bootstrap grid layout?

```css
ul {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="row">
      <li class="col-6 col-md-2">Item 1</li>
      <li class="col-6 col-md-2">Item 2</li>
      <li class="col-6 col-md-2">Item 3</li>
      <li class="col-6 col-md-2">Item 4</li>
      <li class="col-6 col-md-2">Item 5</li>
      <li class="col-6 col-md-2">Item 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```